# Visual Studio Advanced CSS Formatting Beyond Compact to Expanded

Tags: css, visual-studio-2012, formatting

I've been trying find a way to format my css when in Visual Studio

It appears there are only:

Compact:

```
.class {style: style;}
```

Semi Expanded:

```
.class{
    style: style;
}
```

Expanded:

```
.class
{
    style: style;
}
```

If you format as compact, you get something like:

```
.class-one {style: style;}

.class-two {style: style; style: style; style: style;}

.class-two:after {style: style; style: style;}
```

One thing I am trying to remove is the blank line between the css.

Also I was hoping that there is a way to add tabs after the selector. Lets say I want a selector then 5 tabs before the opening {

```
.class-one               {style: style;}
.class-two               {style: style;style: style;style: style;}
.class-two:after         {style: style;style: style;}
```

If anyone knows of a way to change it and save it as a preset that would be nice. If there isn't that's ok too. It wouldn't be the end of the world.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using ReSharper plugin, different formatting options available

[View Here](http://i44.tinypic.com/etaz48.jpg)

To apply Code Cleanup at the current file -> Choose ReSharper | Tools | Cleanup Code

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the late reply. I thought stack overflow would send me an email if I had any responses.